Is it possible to retrieve emails messages sent to multiple particular recipients inside sentitems using microsoft graph Api with PowerShell
I need to be able to retrieve email messages for particular multiple recipients inside sentitems, when i run my code, i get error bad request error 400. Am looping thru each recipient who i need their emails retrieved. The goal is for me to input a number of recipients email addresses that I sent emails then retrieve the emails and save into csv.
The error is present in the request endpoint, my endpoint.
$nextLink = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${mailuser}/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?`$filter=(sentDateTime ge ${startDate})&`$search='to:${recipientUser}'&`$select=sentDateTime,subject,toRecipients,bodyPreview,ccRecipients"
Below is the entire code.
# Azure AD app registration details
$appId = ""
$appSecret = ""
$tenantId = ""

# User to retrieve mail sent messages(your email, since you're the sender)
$mailuser = "myemail@mydomain.com"

# User email addresses that you sent emails to, separated by commas
$recipientUsers = "user1@theirdomain.com", "user2@externaldomain.com"

# Date range for filtering emails
$startDate = '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z'

# Define the folder path to store the results
$tempFolderPath = "C:\Temp"

# Check if the folder exists, if not, create it
if (-not (Test-Path $tempFolderPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $tempFolderPath -ItemType Directory -Force
}

# Define CSV file path
$csvFilePath = "$tempFolderPath\sentitemsemail_data2.csv"

# Define API endpoint and parameters for authentication
$authEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$authBody = @{
    client_id = $appId
    client_secret = $appSecret
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
}

# Define function to get request headers for Graph API
function Get-RequestHeaders {
    $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $authEndpoint -Body $authBody
    $accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

    @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $($accessToken)"
        'Accept' = 'application/json'
    }
}

# Define function to retrieve messages
function Get-Messages {
    param (
        [string]$url
    )

    $requestHeaders = Get-RequestHeaders
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $requestHeaders
}

# Define function to export email object to CSV
function Export-EmailObjectToCSV {
    param (
        [object]$emailObject
    )

    $emailObject | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation
}

# Loop through each recipient user
foreach ($recipientUser in $recipientUsers) {
    # Initialize $nextLink variable with the initial endpoint URL, from $startDate to current date
    $nextLink = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${mailuser}/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?`$filter=(sentDateTime ge ${startDate})&`$search='to:${recipientUser}'&`$select=sentDateTime,subject,toRecipients,bodyPreview,ccRecipients"

    # Loop until all pages are fetched
    do {
        # Retrieve messages for the current page
        $messages = Get-Messages -url $nextLink

        # Loop through each message
        foreach ($message in $messages.value) {
            $subject = $message.subject
            $sentdatetime = $message.sentDateTime
            $bodyPreview = $message.bodyPreview

            # Initialize an array to store all CC recipient addresses
            $ccRecipientAddresses = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

            foreach ($recipient in $message.toRecipients) {
                $recipientName = $recipient.emailAddress.name
                $recipientAddress = $recipient.emailAddress.address

                # Loop through each CC recipient and store their address
                foreach ($torecipient in $message.ccRecipients){
                    [void]$ccRecipientAddresses.Add($torecipient.emailAddress.address)
                }

                # Create a new object to store the data
                $emailObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Subject = $subject
                    RecipientName = $recipientName
                    RecipientAddress = $recipientAddress
                    ToRecipientAddresses = $ccRecipientAddresses -join ", "
                    SentDateTime = $sentdatetime
                    BodyPreview = $bodyPreview
                }

                # Export each email object to the CSV file
                Export-EmailObjectToCSV -emailObject $emailObject
            }
        }

        # Check if there are more pages to fetch
        if ($messages."@odata.nextLink") {
            $nextLink = $messages."@odata.nextLink"
        }
        else {
            $nextLink = $null  # If no more pages, exit the loop
        }
    } while ($nextLink)
}




Yes you can get emails.  Try removing the filter.  Then add filter items one at a time to find the actual error.  I thing the single quotes need to be escaped 'to:${recipientUser}'

can u post the solution mate?

You can't combine $filter and $search query parameters for messages.
Filter can be moved to $search query parameter. Search value must be enclosed in double quotes.
GET /v1.0/users/${mailuser}/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?$search="to:${recipientUser} AND sent>=${startDate}"&$select=sentDateTime,subject,toRecipients,bodyPreview,ccRecipients

PS
$nextLink = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${mailuser}/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?&`$search=""to:${recipientUser} AND sent>=${startDate}""&`$select=sentDateTime,subject,toRecipients,bodyPreview,ccRecipients"


My brother, thanks so much for correction. it worked. one more query, if i need to query inbox folder, inside search query can i modify the search like this $search=""from:${senderUser} AND receive>=${startDate}"" ?

i created something like this for inbox folder n i get 404 not found error , yet the users in the loop exists$nextLink = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${mailuser}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?&`$search=""from:${senderUser} AND received>=${startDate}""&`$select=receivedDateTime,subject,bodyPreview"

Could you share error code and error message which should be a part of a response.

Hi Mate, it worked. I had referenced wrong source address that is the owner of the mailbox was incorrect. I changed and now am able to export emails for inbox folder just as sentitems. Your answer really worked. Thank you so much.
